Azure ML job rerun if dataset content changed but version is same?
I am wondering whether a Azure ML job, is able to detect that the content of an input dataset has changed if the version stays constant?
I could not find documentation on the rerun/recycle criteria. Only a troubleshooting guide which specifies that inputs need to be identical for recycling, without explaining how far the comparison goes.
My tests are inconclusive. First, it looked like changes were detected (jobs were always rerun) but then, suddenly, jobs started to get recycled all the time. But possibly some settings changed in between, although I do not remember changing anything...
Context:
We want to have daily Azure ML jobs running on our incoming, un-versioned data.
To give Azure ML access to the data, we want to use an Azure ML dataset which simply points to the storage and always stays at version 1.
The ML code consumes all data which are on the provided storage path.
Between each daily job, the data on the storage might change (more files, less files, same files with different content, same files with modified timestamps) or stay constant.
Ideally, the Azure ML job would recognize when the data on the storage changed and rerun the job. If the data did not change, ideally Azure ML would recycle the previous job.
Thanks!

Provide the documentation you referred.

@JayashankarGS, link added. Here too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-debug-pipeline-reuse-issues?view=azureml-api-2#how-does-reuse-work

The data asset, being in the old version with frequent changes in files in storage, will still cause the pipeline to re-run the job.
It is also mentioned in the document that if there are any changes in inputs, the pipeline will re-run the job.
If you're not getting expected results, try to debug with the steps given in the document you provided. Mainly, check step 5, where it is mentioned how to compare the input dataset among different pipeline jobs and to know the difference between those pipeline components.
I have tried with different data in the same CSV file and data asset version, and it successfully takes those changed data.
To compare enable the below option

Then go to pipeline job and add it in compare list.

Then you will get the option to compare by graph and details.

If you see in below image, I ran three job. 1st and 2nd job run is with different dataset and 2nd and 3rd run is with same dataset and the dataset version is same in inputDatasets value and it doesn't highlight that as different but if you see last job it took only 44 seconds it means it reused the 2nd run.


For the special case of using scheduled runs, it looks like change of data in the folder a dataset points to is not detected. Jobs will be recycled, as shown in the screenshot.
Manually running the schedule will also not detect the changes.
However, running the pipeline, which is identical to the one run by the schedule, will re-run the entire pipeline.
So for our special case, we have to balance the benefit & costs of force-re-running the schedule every day, even without changes to the data, vs running pipelines on-demand, but having to wait for the results.


It seems like it is running the pipeline again but when you wait for results it actually re used old results for not changing data.
